# Newbie C++ question about functions and error checking

Tags: c++

Am working on a small problem and have spent quite a few hours trying to figure out what I did wrong. Using Dev++ compiler which at times has some cryptic error messages.

I tried to make the Volume calculation a function and got it to work but I have 2 small nits. Will work on error checking after I resolve this.

1. With the function added, for some reason with dev++ now, the program does not pause (press any key to continue).
2. Volume is coming up with blank instead of a number.

Thanks
PC

```
// The purpose of this program is to determine the Volume of a
// square-based pyramid after the user inputs the Area and
// the Height.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
double calcvolume(double a, double h) 
{ 
    double volume;
    volume = ( a * h ) / 3; 
    return (volume);

} 

int main()
{                                 
   double area, height, volume;                    // declare variables

   cout << "Please enter the Area of the Square-based pyramid:";       // requests users input
   cin >> area;                                                        // assigns user input to area

   cout << "Please enter the Height of the Square-based pyramid:";     // requests user input
   cin >> height;    
                                                   // assigns user input to height
   cout << "Area= " << area << "\n";                                   // Prints user input for area
   cout << "Height= " << height << "\n";  
   calcvolume(area,height);     

   cout << "Volume= " << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << volume << "\n";    // Prints resolution to the formula stored in volume

    system("pause"); // forces DOS window to pause to allow user to utilize program
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're asking for help on writing a function to do the calculation, post what you've already come up with, and we'll help you from there.

Comment: We'd rather see what you wrote that did not work - we can't help fix working code.

Comment: Showing what works as opposed to what does not is not useful if you need help figuring out why things aren't working.

Comment: Where is the actual question? None of the sentences given above end with question mark. Either you're asking for ready-to-copy solution or for brainstorming, but please be explicit then and post a wiki.

Comment: Do you mean Bloodshed Dev-C++ by "Dev++ compiler"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated code looks correct, but you aren't storing the calcvolume return value.  The volume variable you declare in calcvolume is different than the one you declare in main.  Each of these variables can only be referenced from within the function it is declared in.

In order to save the volume,

`calcvolume(area,height);`

should be

`volume = calcvolume(area,height);`

This will store the value being returned from calcvolume in the `volume` variable in your main function.

Comment: Interesting. I thought volume would be set and returned via the function. Well I'll be..
Thanks
PC

Comment: You could gain such behavior by declaring the parameters for `calcvolume` to be references.  I'd advise you to spend some more time looking into tutorials and guides to C++ programming though, it's a monster of a language to dive into on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result of `calcvolume(area,height)` to main's `volume` as follows:

```
volume = calcvolume(area,height);
```

Now you can safely use main's volume variable.

I'm guessing that your program was not even reaching the `system("pause")` line, and was crashing the line above. It could be because `volume` was never set to anything and was holding garbage data. This garbage data made `cout << ...` fail.

Before you fix the `calcvolume(area,height)` line, try fixing your variable declarations so that your variables are initialized to zero:

```
double area=0.0, height=0.0, volume=0.0;  // declare variables
```

Now run it again and see if it outputs `Volume=0.00` and pauses.

It's always good to initialize your variables to zero or something meaningful. Otherwise, they will be initialized to random data (whatever was already in those memory bytes) and will make troubleshooting more difficult.